# snmpd won't generate traps

Tags: debian, net-snmp, snmpd

I'm trying to get snmpd to inform our monitoring system when an event such as low disk space takes place. I'm using snmpd on Debian 8.

My snmpd.conf file looks like this:

```
##
# Daemon
##

agentAddress udp:161
master agentx
dontLogTCPWrappersConnects 1

##
# Authentication
##

agentSecName authOnlyUser
#rouser internalUser
view systemonly included .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view systemonly included .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
rocommunity modify
rouser authOnlyUser
rwuser authPrivUser priv

##
# Process Monitoring
##

proc sshd

proc ntpd
proc nginx



##
# Disk Monitoring
#   10MBs required on root disk, 5% free on /var, 10% free on all other disks
##

disk       /     10000
disk       /var  5%
includeAllDisks  10%

##
# System Load
##

monitor machineTooBusy hrProcessorLoad > 90
load   12 10 5      # Unacceptable 1-, 5-, and 15-minute load averages

##
# Event MIB - automatically generate alerts
##

defaultMonitors          yes
linkUpDownNotifications  no

##
# Send events to spectrum
##

informsink 172.16.102.98 public
```

When I run `snmpd -Lo -d -r 10 -f` I'll both stop nginx and intentionally fill up a file system. I don't end up seeing any traps sent. If I run tcpdump, I can see the startup and shutdown traps being sent, but no others are generated.

I do have an "authOnlyUser" user created.

I'm sure I'm doing something simple and silly, but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: Just to be sure, if it's root you're trying to fill up....look at this: http://serverfault.com/questions/315181/df-says-disk-is-full-but-it-is-not . You might not actually be getting down under 10MB (and for / that number is scary low by the way).

Comment: That's a good point. I should set that limit higher. I've been filling up /home as my test.