# /dev/vda1 - Can't find missing space

Tags: linux

I had a system that ran out of space due to the journal getting full.  So I vaccumed that and recovered the space, but while looking at that, I noticed that the system is using half it's drive space on /dev/vda1 but I can't figure out where the rest went.

Shutdown and rebooted, then ran ncdu as root - no help.  What else can I check?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           795M  756K  794M   1% /run
/dev/vda1       151G   71G   72G  50% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm



    7.8 GiB [##########]  swapfile
    1.9 GiB [##        ] /usr
    1.3 GiB [#         ] /var
   82.1 MiB [          ] /boot
    7.9 MiB [          ] /etc
    2.0 MiB [          ] /home
  756.0 KiB [          ] /run
   92.0 KiB [          ] /root
   56.0 KiB [          ] /tmp
e  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
   12.0 KiB [          ] /media
   12.0 KiB [          ] /opt
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /srv
.   0.0   B [          ] /proc
    0.0   B [          ] /sys
    0.0   B [          ] /dev
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
@   0.0   B [          ]  libx32
@   0.0   B [          ]  lib64
@   0.0   B [          ]  lib32
@   0.0   B [          ]  sbin
@   0.0   B [          ]  lib
@   0.0   B [          ]  bin
<   0.0   B [          ]  mnt
```

Comment: What file system is there and have you performed a (forced) integrity check?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [df in linux not showing correct free space after file removal](https://serverfault.com/questions/232525/df-in-linux-not-showing-correct-free-space-after-file-removal)

Answer (score 1):

A comment at the following link pointed me in the right direction.

I unmounted my backup drive - /mnt/BACKUP

Then I looked on the local file system (/dev/vda1) and found /mnt/BACKUP folder that had a huge backup in it.  So /mnt/BACKUP (the real external drive) must have go unmounted and then the backup happened, then the external drive got mounted. Odd, but fixed now!

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537156/centos-6-ran-out-of-space-need-to-reclaim-it